# Finding out if someone has been the recipient of multiple bounties from the same person is tedious to say the least

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, bounty, moderation

The transfer of reputation via bounties is one way unscrupulous users can get round voting limits or increase the reputation of sock puppets without triggering the vote fraud tools.

The tooltip that we get on the answer itself shows who awarded the bounty. However, the tooltip on the recipient's profile page doesn't. This means we have to go to each answer in turn to check the donor and see if there's anything nefarious afoot.

Can we show who awarded the bounty on the tooltips on the recipient's profile page - in the same way that they are on the actual answer.

Comment: I think this is the longest time a post on meta has gone without a first comment ever.

Comment: @MsYvetteǝʇʇǝʌʎsW Probably because there's not much to say other than "OK, sure, sounds fine to me."

Comment: @PeterOlson I'm enjoying the uncomplicatedness and controverisalessness of this post :D

Comment: **The game is on !** - Sherlock Holmes

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Done. The bounty amount tooltip in the "earned" tab of the user profiles now includes the bounty awarder name. Hope that helps!

[image]

Comment: I assume that this is network wide?

Comment: @ChrisF Doesn't appear to be, I don't get any tool tip on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Seth odd. I wouldn't have expected it to be site specific. Maybe it hasn't been deployed across all sites yet.

Comment: @Seth it works on Chemistry.

Comment: @ChrisF Oops. It does work. I hadn't clicked "view more" to get on the actual page.

Answer (score 37):

I can't help with your feature request but this SEDE query attempts to find the answer to your question: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/446948/users-receiving-multiple-bounties-from-the-same-person

Comment: A winner called “repeat” getting lots of bounties from a user called “false” at the top result…..

Comment: Adding "HAVING COUNT(*)>5 AND SUM(bounty_data.bounty_end_amount) > 1000" gives 44 results, these would make a good starting point for an investigation.

Comment: For future visitors, so that you do not have to go and visit each profile of the visitors manually if you're suspicious of the winners of the query, here are the links. User [Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915/repeat) who has received 61 bounties worth reputation 11550 from User [false](http://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false)

Comment: Also, I have a feeling that this query is wrong. The query shows that reputation 11550 has been awarded to [User Repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915/repeat?tab=profile) by [User False](http://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=profile), but currently, User Repeat has 10855 reputation. I know he could have received downvotes, but he has many high scoring posts, and I don't think he could have received so many downvotes.

Comment: I found [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) has received 7 bounties from [Ken Kin](http://stackoverflow.com/users/927012/ken-kin), quite suspicious!

Comment: @AshishAhujaツ [repeate](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4609915/repeat?tab=profile) has create 30 bounties worth 6.600 reputation, 26 of them earned by [mat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat), worth 5750 reputation, [mat](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1613573/mat) also earned 49 bounties worth 9300 reputation from [false](http://stackoverflow.com/users/772868/false?tab=profile)

Comment: The prolog mafia;)

Comment: @Sakura I think maybe just flag for mod attention if you have doubts and we shouldn't discuss it here. I was just being light hearted with Andras mafia remark and the Jon Skeet rep comment.. I really don't want to be involved in any meta drama today, been too much lately... :D see [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318485/finding-out-if-someone-has-been-the-recipient-of-multiple-bounties-from-the-same/318515?noredirect=1#comment318809_318485)