# A question regarding "promotional bounties"

Tags: discussion, bounty

I have recently spent some time collecting information to write an answer to an old question because I haven't found a similarly complete answer on Stack Overflow on that topic (i.e., I felt it wasn't enough information on SO on that topic).

The aim was to make the people spend less time while getting acquainted with that topic, so I was going to start a bounty to (potentially) lift my answer a bit by attracting attention to the answer and it receiving votes.

While choosing the minimal bounty amount, I've noticed that it is 100, not 50. Digging in the help center, I've found the following line:

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

I'm **absolutely fine** with 100 rep spend instead of 50, that doesn't really matter, but!

I'm not sure about the point it makes - "overly promotional bounties", so I've got a couple of questions:

- Does it mean that I'm discouraged to start a bounty on a post that I've already posted answer to and *because of this* I'm getting a "penalty" of 50 points?
- Does it mean the system is just trying to prevent getting "easy points" (i.e., invest - profit)? Though I'm not seeing this possible - if an answer is easy, it must have been provided already, if it's not easy and being long, then those points are not easy points.
- What promoting is considered to be *overly* promoting?

Comment: Basically... placing a bounty on a question greatly increases the number of eyes on that question and it's answers, thus potentially resulting in a large influx of upvotes. A 50 point bounty rather easily pays for itself with that effect when you already know that there's a high quality answer there that is likely to soak them up.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yep, you guessed it:

> Does it mean the system is just trying to prevent getting "easy points" (i.e., invest - profit)? Though I'm not seeing this possible - if an answer is easy, it must have been provided already, if it's not easy and being long, then those points are not easy points.

As with most of the weird restrictions in place on bounties, this was added because **originally** it *was* open to abuse. When hitting the "break-even" point on offering a bounty involves annoying a substantial number of people, it's hard to argue that these bounties are serving a useful purpose - it's one thing to get a bit of extra visibility for an answer that you worked hard on, another to keep it pinned for weeks and weeks while you exhaust every last bit of interest in it.

#### See also:

- ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit)
- [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack)

Comment: When starting a bounty, can I explicitly state in the notice that I'm starting it to attract attention to my answer or I should make it look like a general draw-attention? I haven't found a reason in the bounty dialog saying "Attract attention to the new answer", for example.

Comment: You should [always be honest](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318497/what-exactly-is-artificial-inflation-of-reputation-and-where-is-the-line/318499#318499) when offering a bounty.

Comment: No, these messages cannot be edited.

Comment: (Nor can't the notice be removed and another one added?)

Comment: Well, the *remove* bit is easy, but the other bit... Not so much.

Comment: Alternative fix: Answers posted by the bounty poster don't generate rep while the bounty is open.

Comment: @Raphael Then why let the answerer post a bounty on question they answered at all? I don't think they are trying to prevent promotional bounties, just discourage them for most answers.

Comment: @Clint  I never even considered the idea of posting a bounty to promote _my own_ answer, so I don't come at it from the same perspective. Promoting a question or answer by another person should be possible, yes; promoting your own, why? Write a blog post.

Comment: @Raphael I haven't considered posting a bounty to promote my own answer either, but I don't think it's a bad thing. The changes made to prevent "overly promotional" bounties reflect that. Promoting your answer is fine, doing it for every answer or for the same answer multiple times should be discouraged, and it is. As to why, Shog answers that in the answer above.