# Why can a second bounty only be 500?

Tags: support, bounty

I set a bounty on this question: [How can I communicate to the user's browser that a POST request it made is side-effect-free?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60016749/how-can-i-communicate-to-the-users-browser-that-a-post-request-it-made-is-side#)

and I have accepted an answer and rewarded the bounty. But there is another answer to the question that I decided I wanted to give a "second prize" bounty to, say 200. One of the options for "reason for setting a bounty" is "one of the answers is exemplary and worth extra recognition" or something like that, so I assume (though I haven't gone through with the process) that this is a means of just immediately granting the value of the bounty to an existing answer.

After refreshing the page, the "start a bounty" option is present again. But it only lets me set a bounty of 500! I distinctly remember that when I set the first bounty, it offered me various values less than 500. Why is 500 my only option now?

[image: "start a bounty" faux-modal popup with only 500 as an option]

Comment: You can only create bounties that are higher than the previous one. 500 is the max amount however so it’s capped at that.

Comment: "You can only create bounties that are higher than the previous one" - Why not? This is obviously unreasonable. I have demonstrated a good reason for wishing to award an additional bounty of more or less arbitrary value. I should be able to do it.

Comment: From the help center: *To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50). Additionally, if you offer multiple bounties on the same question, the minimum spend doubles with each subsequent bounty (50 reputation on the first bounty, 100 reputation on the second, 200 on the third, and so on).*

Comment: So no, thanks to past bounty abuse you are not able to do this.

Comment: Can you explain why the use case I describe would be "overly promotional" or otherwise an abuse of the system? What does the phrase "overly promotional" even mean? I reiterate: this policy is stupid, and I ought to be able to do what I'm describing.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365490/a-question-regarding-promotional-bounties and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit

Comment: Sorry you feel the policy is stupid, but it is not going to change.

Comment: @Hammerite it's more 'the old way, which let you do what you want, was also prone to abuse. So it was changed'. The change wasn't meant to stop your use case. It's an after effect. But the change does mean your use case won't work

Comment: This is why it pays to read the instructions first. Knowing how the bounty system works, one could award the lower bounty first, then the higher one.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey, and how would I have done that? The first bounty was created prior to any answers being posted and was necessary to get the two-day-old question any attention at all. The option to create a second bounty did not appear until after the first bounty had already been awarded. The course of action you propose is not possible. I would suggest that this would have been obvious to you had you read and understood the question, and that you should take your own advice regarding reading and understanding things before acting.

Comment: Even if it were the case that I would have been able to create a second 200-point bounty had I done so after creating the 500-point bounty (but before awarding it), to make the creation of the 200-point bounty impossible as a side effect of awarding the 500-point one would clearly be a "gotcha".

Answer (score 1):

A bounty must be at least double the previous one. The previous bounty must have been 250+, and 500 is the max bounty, which is why it is the only one available.